The role of the roll off factor in synchronization
Here is a statement in a book titled "Wireless Communications from the Ground Up" which I tried to understand and could not:
" Excess bandwidth provides the energy required for timing and frequency synchronization"
Fred Harris
Can someone in simple terms explain why does a larger BW ( larger roll off factor) help timing and frequency synchronization ?

Is that the book on SDR? If so, the author doesn't seem to be Harris. So is that quote coming from the book or from someone commenting about the book? Links and/or references, plus some more discussion from you and your own perspective, may each help you get a more useful answer.

No the author of the book is not Fred Harris , but the statement or quote  inside the book is apparently from Fred Harris. Yes the book is on SDR

Does Roll-Off Factor in the Pulse Shaping section of PySDR: A Guide to SDR and DSP using Python help?

It does because it shows that with a higher roll off factor the impulse response decays faster which reduces the probability of ISI in case of inaccurate symbol timing recovery. However I thought that there is more into it than that , not sure though. Anyway thank you , I appreciate your input


Excess bandwidth provides the energy required for timing and frequency synchronization

That's because there's something unsaid about the minimum bandwidth for a transmission channel: that bandwidth assumes that the transmitter and receiver run from the same clock. The minimum bandwidth calculation does not take into account any bandwidth needed to accommodate successful demodulation of the signal without a time reference.
Normally the receiver's clock is not phase-synchronized to the transmitter's clock, and there needs to be additional data in the channel that would allow such synchronization. Thus, you'll need bandwidth in excess to what merely sending the information over the channel requires.
For sufficiently narrow bandwidths, the timing reference for both the transmitter and the receiver can be provided by navigation satellites (GPS, GLONASS, Galileo, etc.). At some point though, the quality of the local oscillator required to keep steady phase is such that the receiver would not be economical. Thus, usually, instead of putting a $3000 atomic clock-on-a-chip into a receiver and transmitter, it's easier to allocate some bandwidth to timing recovery and synchronization.
To make it clear: we're not talking about absolute time and date, only abut having the same frequency, without phase drift, as the transmitter does. So this is not about synchronizing time as if you had two wristwatches that needed to be synchronized. It is about synchronizing the rates at which the clocks run.

Another way to think of it is: data that's optimally encoded and modulated on a channel is indistinguishable from band-limited random noise. There's no way to recover timing from it in general, if the contents of the sent data are completely unknown, but only the encoding and modulation schemes are known. There are ways around it when something is known about the data, and that allows e.g. GPS receivers to synchronize with the overlapping data streams coming from the satellites. But then, the data streams were designed to recover timing from them.

Or just use a CDR in your DSP :)

The more bandwidth, the more storage capacity is available for communication, which helps synch better in timing and frequency.
For example, consider your PC hard drive. The more space it has, the swifter it is in navigating through files, copying, or whatever we want to do, and searching or executing files becomes much slower when space is less.
So excess bandwidth provides more space/capacity for communication than it requires.
If you have any more doubts please comment below.
